# SQL Server 2012 - Help 'Plugging In' Table to Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below to create an amortization schedule on a loan given the manually entered variables (labeled):

```
DECLARE @PV as Float = -290000 --Loan Amount
,@FV as float = 0 --Value of the loan at termination
,@Term as float = 30 --The term of the loan in years
,@Pay_type as bit = 0 --Identifies the payment as due at the end (0) or the beginning (1) of the period
,@annual_rate as float = .03375 --The annual rate of interest
,@payment_frequency as float = 12 --The number of payments in a year
,@startdate as datetime = '07/31/2016'
,@rate as float
,@nper as float

Set @rate = @annual_rate/@payment_frequency
Set @nper = @Term * @payment_frequency

;WITH
Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )
SELECT n as [Period]
,CASE @payment_frequency
  WHEN 13 THEN DATEADD(week,4*n,@startdate)
  WHEN 26 THEN DATEADD(week,2*n,@startdate)
  WHEN 52 THEN DATEADD(week,n,@startdate)
  ELSE DATEADD(M,12*n/@payment_frequency,@startdate) END as [Due Date]
,-wct.PV(@rate,@nper-(n-  1) 
,wct.PMT(@rate,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type),@FV,@pay_type) as [Starting Balance]
,wct.PMT(@rate,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type) as [Payment]
,wct.IPMT(@rate,n,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type) as [Interest Payment]
,wct.PPMT(@rate,n,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type) as [Principal Payment]
,-wct.PV(@rate,@nper-n,wct.PMT(@rate,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type),@FV,@pay_type) as [Ending Balance]
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
       FROM Nbrs ) D( n )
WHERE n <= @nper
```

What I am trying to do, is have this query pull from a table (dbo.Loans) of loans that already have assigned values for the variables (i.e. PV, term, rate, etc). I am thinking turning this into a table-valued function would be best, but I am not too experienced with functions and cannot get the proper coding down.

Comment: Be very careful here. This appears to be a financial application and you have everything defined as floats. Floats can lose accuracy because they are approximate datatypes. It really starts to show up with doing things like calculating payments because dividing with floats ends with values that can't be stored accurately. You would likely be better off using numeric datatypes. And of course with things like number of payments in a year, an int would make far more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your logic into a [Table-Valued User-Defined Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) that has all the necessary input parameters and returns a table having a structure corresponding to your final SELECT. Something like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetAmortizationSchedule
(
    @LoanId INT
    -- other input paramters may come here
)
RETURNS @sheduleTable TABLE 
(
    DueDate DATE,
    StartingBalance NUMERIC(18, 4), -- as already mentioned, fixed-point numbers should be used
    Payment NUMERIC(18, 4)
    -- other result columns come here
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PV as Float  --Loan Amount
    ,@FV as float --Value of the loan at termination
    ,@Term as float  --The term of the loan in years
    ,@Pay_type as bit  --Identifies the payment as due at the end (0) or the beginning (1) of the period
    ,@annual_rate as float  --The annual rate of interest
    ,@payment_frequency as float  --The number of payments in a year
    ,@startdate as datetime 
    ,@rate as float
    ,@nper as float

    SELECT @PV = PV, @FV = FV, @Term = Term
        -- other variable assignment here
    FROM dbo.Loan 
    WHERE LoanId = @LoadId

    Set @rate = @annual_rate/@payment_frequency
    Set @nper = @Term * @payment_frequency

    ;WITH
    Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
    Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
    Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
    Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
    Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )

    -- inserting data into the result table 
    INSERT INTO @sheduleTable 
    (DueDate, StartingBalance, Payment /* other columns */)
    SELECT n as [Period]
    ,CASE @payment_frequency
      WHEN 13 THEN DATEADD(week,4*n,@startdate)
      WHEN 26 THEN DATEADD(week,2*n,@startdate)
      WHEN 52 THEN DATEADD(week,n,@startdate)
      ELSE DATEADD(M,12*n/@payment_frequency,@startdate) END as [Due Date]
    ,-wct.PV(@rate,@nper-(n-  1) 
    ,wct.PMT(@rate,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type),@FV,@pay_type) as [Starting Balance]
    ,wct.PMT(@rate,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type) as [Payment]
    ,wct.IPMT(@rate,n,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type) as [Interest Payment]
    ,wct.PPMT(@rate,n,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type) as [Principal Payment]
    ,-wct.PV(@rate,@nper-n,wct.PMT(@rate,@nper,@PV,@FV,@pay_type),@FV,@pay_type) as [Ending Balance]
    FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
           FROM Nbrs ) D( n )
    WHERE n <= @nper
END
GO
```

Comment: As posted this is a multi-statement table valued function. The performance of these is dreadful. Even worse than scalar functions. This needs to be a single statement.

Comment: That is correct. From my experience, such computation should be implemented in C#, Java, C++ or similar language, as it is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this as an inline table valued function. The problem however is you seem to have a scalar function wct in here. That is going to cripple your performance. I also added some white space to your query so it is a lot more legible.

```
create function AmoritzationSchedule
(
    @PV as Float = -290000 --Loan Amount
    ,@FV as float = 0 --Value of the loan at termination
    ,@Term as float = 30 --The term of the loan in years
    ,@Pay_type as bit = 0 --Identifies the payment as due at the end (0) or the beginning (1) of the period
    ,@annual_rate as float = .03375 --The annual rate of interest
    ,@payment_frequency as float = 12 --The number of payments in a year
    ,@startdate as datetime = '07/31/2016'
)RETURNS TABLE as RETURN

WITH
Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )
SELECT n as [Period]
    ,CASE @payment_frequency
        WHEN 13 THEN DATEADD(week, 4 * n, @startdate)
        WHEN 26 THEN DATEADD(week, 2 * n, @startdate)
        WHEN 52 THEN DATEADD(week, n, @startdate)
        ELSE DATEADD(Month, 12 * n / @payment_frequency, @startdate) 
    END as [Due Date]
    , - wct.PV((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), (@Term * @payment_frequency) - (n - 1), wct.PMT((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), (@Term * @payment_frequency), @PV, @FV, @pay_type), @FV, @pay_type) as [Starting Balance]
    , wct.PMT((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), (@Term * @payment_frequency), @PV, @FV, @pay_type) as [Payment]
    , wct.IPMT((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), n, (@Term * @payment_frequency), @PV, @FV, @pay_type) as [Interest Payment]
    , wct.PPMT((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), n, (@Term * @payment_frequency), @PV, @FV, @pay_type) as [Principal Payment]
    , - wct.PV((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), (@Term * @payment_frequency) - n, wct.PMT((@annual_rate / @payment_frequency), (@Term * @payment_frequency), @PV, @FV, @pay_type), @FV, @pay_type) as [Ending Balance]
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
       FROM Nbrs ) D( n )
WHERE n <= (@Term * @payment_frequency)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions, I was actually able to come up with this to solve my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #Loans
(
 LoanNumber nvarchar(50)
,PV DECIMAL(18,8) --Loan Amount
,FV DECIMAL(18,8) --Value of the loan at termination
,Term DECIMAL(18,8) --The term of the loan in years
,Pay_type BIT --Identifies the payment as due at the end (0) or the beginning (1) of the period
,annual_rate DECIMAL(18,8) --The annual rate of interest
,payment_frequency DECIMAL(18,8) --The number of payments in a year
,FirstPayment DATETIME
,rate AS (annual_rate / payment_frequency)
,nper AS (Term * payment_frequency)
);

INSERT INTO #Loans
(
 LoanNumber
,PV
,FV
,Term
,Pay_type
,annual_rate
,payment_frequency
,FirstPayment
)
select top 5
 a.LoanNumber
,a.PV
,0 as FV
,a.NewLoanTerm30yrFxd/12 as Term
,0 as Pay_Type
,a.EstNewRate30yrFxd/100 as annual_rate
,12 as Payment_Frequency
,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0)) as FirstPayment
from #LoanPool a
;


WITH
Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 ),
RowNbrs ( n ) AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM Nbrs )

SELECT 
 a.LoanNumber
,D.n as [Period]
,CASE a.payment_frequency
    WHEN 13 THEN DATEADD(week,4*n,a.FirstPayment)
    WHEN 26 THEN DATEADD(week,2*n,a.FirstPayment)
    WHEN 52 THEN DATEADD(week,n,a.FirstPayment)
    ELSE DATEADD(M,12*n/a.payment_frequency,a.FirstPayment)
END as [Due Date]
,-wct.PV(a.rate,a.nper-(n-1),wct.PMT(a.rate,a.nper,a.PV,a.FV,a.pay_type),a.FV,a.pay_type) AS [Starting Balance]
,wct.PMT(a.rate,a.nper,a.PV,a.FV,a.pay_type) AS [Payment]
,wct.IPMT(a.rate,n,a.nper,a.PV,a.FV,a.pay_type) AS [Interest Payment]
,wct.PPMT(a.rate,n,a.nper,a.PV,a.FV,a.pay_type) AS [Principal Payment]
,-wct.PV(a.rate,a.nper-n,wct.PMT(a.rate,a.nper,a.PV,a.FV,a.pay_type),a.FV,a.pay_type) AS [Ending Balance] 
into #Amortization

FROM 
RowNbrs AS D
   CROSS APPLY #Loans AS a
WHERE 
n <= a.nper
order by a.LoanNumber, [Due Date]
```